# The use of enum without a variable name

Tags: c++

I understand the first one but the second one? When and why would you do that?

```
enum cartoon { HOMER, MARGE, BART, LISA, MAGGIE };

enum { HOMER, MARGE, BART, LISA, MAGGIE };
```

Comment: @Noah: you made me think that perhaps it is indeed illegal and I am misleading, so I compiled a test similar to my example below on g++. It compiles and runs ok, although online references I've checked indeed don't show this syntax option.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you can define such enum in a **class**, which gives it a scope, and helps expose class's capabilities, e.g.

```
class Encryption {
public:
  enum { DEFAUTL_KEYLEN=16, SHORT_KEYLEN=8, LONG_KEYLEN=32 };
  // ...
};

byte key[Encryption::DEFAUTL_KEYLEN];
```

Comment: Now I see, I was wondering about how'd you use/access it. So it brings it into scope and using it by doing the ClassName::enum value, so basically enum { blah,hah,lol } are then accessible via ClassName::blah and so forth. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This simply creates constant expressions that have the respective values, without a type other than simply `int`, so you can't use an unnamed enum as a type for anything, you will have to simply accept an `int` and then do comparison with the constant.

Something like this:

```
void doSomething(int c);
```

Versus something like this:

```
void doSomething(cartoon c);
```

By the way, your implementation would be the same, so in the case of unnamed enums, the only real drawback is strong typing.

Comment: Except they aren't actually constants, they're *constant expressions*.  There's a sometimes big difference.  For example, you can take a reference or address to a constant.  You can't do that with enum symbols.

Answer (score 7):

The second is an unnamed `enum`. I can be useful when you need the fields, but you don't intend to ever declare a variable of this enumeration type.

To provide a 'very C++' example of its use, you will often seen this in template metaprogramming where the enum is used as a 'compile time return value' without the intent of ever declaring a variable of this type :

```
template<class T>
struct some_metafunction
{
    enum { res = 0; };
};
```

Comment: Is the `= 0;` part actually necessary?

Comment: @Jacob It's not, but it's just an example (usually the value of `res` will depend on `T`)

Answer (score 7):

I am just providing a real life example use of anonyous enum, which I encountered in an embedded project. 
In the project, EEPROM is used to stored some parameters. Let's assume these parameters are those carton charater's ages, each parameter has the size of 1 byte in continuous address.

These parameters are copied into an array stored in ROM when the processor is powered on.

```
uint8_t ROM_AGE[END_AGE]
```

If we define an anomymous enum here:

```
enum { HOMER_AGE, MARGE_AGE, BART_AGE, LISA_AGE, MAGGIE_AGE, END_AGE };
```

Then the key words in enum can be used to index the age of each character like `ROM_AGE[HOMER_AGE]` . 
By using this enum, the readability is much better than using `ROM_AGE[0]`.

Comment: The last entry `END_AGE` can be used as a counter, since its value is the number of entries of the anonymous enum. Hence, we can loop over `ROM_AGE` in a for-loop, as in `for(int i=0; i<END_AGE; ++i)`, and adding more entries to the anonymous enum at a later point will not break the for-loops.

Answer (score 4):

enum, union, struct and class have a common part in the syntax share the same 
This unamed pattern is rarelly used.
But sometime you may found this.

```
typedef enum { HOMER, MARGE, BART, LISA, MAGGIE } cartoont;
```

Or if you have a single variable containing only a few state.

```
enum { HOMER, MARGE, BART, LISA, MAGGIE } my_var;
```

This avoid the following declaration.

```
enum cartoon { HOMER, MARGE, BART, LISA, MAGGIE };
cartoon my_var;
```