# need a robust error system for a win32 gui application

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, error-handling

I have some code that looks as follows:

```
void MyClass::OnButtonClick()
{
    int retVal = SomeDialog.DoModal();
    if(retVal == MYCLASS_ERROR)
    {
        MessageBox("Error"...blah ...blah);
    }
    else if(retVal == IDOK)   // IDOK is returned on clicking the 'OK' button
    {
        MessageBox("All is well"...blah ...blah);
    }
}
```

- `SomeDialog` just shows a progress bar. On any error, the progress bar is automatically closed by calling `EndDialog(MYCLASS_ERROR)`. Only on successful completion will the user be allowed to click on 'OK' there.
- `MYCLASS_ERROR` is a value in an `enum` which contains all sorts of
  return types and statuses.

I found that on clicking OK in `SomeDialog`, the error message still displayed! I dug a little deeper and found that `MYCLASS_ERROR` = `IDOK` = 1.

So my question is, how should I define all these return statuses such that it doesn't collide with any other implementation's statuses? Meaning, my functions should return values that is not returned by **any** other function (or as few other functions as possible).

I thought of modifying my design such that all functions only returned TRUE or FALSE. But, this would not be feasible in all cases. I have also searched quite a bit for answers and haven't found any thus far.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to work around this, but they're kind of ugly.

The cleanest design is usually the one that avoids clashing with standard Win32 idioms, and in the world of Win32, modal dialogs return one of the `ID` values to indicate the button that the user clicked when dismissing them (just like message boxes). Strictly speaking, it's the `nResult` parameter that was passed to the `EndDialog` function used to close the modal dialog box.

I recommend not trying to overload this return value with additional meaning. Trying to do so will just run you into trouble (for example, you probably *also* haven't noticed yet that a return value of -1 means that the creation of the dialog box failed).

Instead, define an additional member variable in your dialog class and use this to report your additional information. On success, you will return `IDOK` from the dialog. On failure (*any* kind of failure), return something like `IDCANCEL`. Your code inside of `OnButtonClick` would then check to see if the return value is `IDOK` or `IDCANCEL`. If it's `IDCANCEL`, then you *also* need to query the value of the member variable you added to the dialog for additional information.

Hopefully that made sense. If not, maybe this code example will (assume that `m_errStatus` is the member variable you added to your subclass of `CDialog`):

```
void MyClass::OnButtonClick()
{
    if (SomeDialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        // Success!
        // The OK button was clicked, so IDOK was returned.
        MessageBox("All is well"...blah ...blah);
    }
    else
    {
        // Failure!
        // Some error occurred, so IDCANCEL (or any other value) was returned.
        // Determine what to do now, based on additional information that the
        // dialog set upon failure.
        switch (SomeDialog.m_errStatus)
        {
            case MYCLASS_ERROR_1:
                MessageBox("Error 1 occurred.");
                break;
            case MYCLASS_ERROR_2:
                MessageBox("Error 2 occurred.");
                break;
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm this sounds best. But what about other functions? For example, worker threads, helper functions, etc. What kind of values should they return? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Anish: Hmm, that's a little tougher. You could probably get by with directly returning one of your enumerated error codes there, because there isn't already a standard idiom for their return values. But error handling via return codes is pretty difficult to get right, and this is only one of the reasons. Honestly, I wonder if you shouldn't just be using exceptions. This is C++ after all, not C.

Comment: I would use exceptions but I'm actually interfacing with many DLLs coded in C. So I thought I'd try and make things uniform. But alas, it doesn't seem to be working too well.

Comment: @Anish Error handling doesn't have to be uniform. Obviously the C DLLs are going to have to return error codes, but that doesn't mean the C++ functions that use them have to return error codes as well. I would definitely recommend throwing exceptions. They make your life so much easier on many levels. There just aren't a lot of good reasons anymore for *not* using exceptions, particularly in UI code (which is what you appear to be writing in C++ since you're using MFC). Even if exceptions are "slow" (which they're not anymore), that's irrelevant in UI code.

Comment: Hmm okay. Time to brush up on my exception knowledge then! Thanks a lot! If possible and if you have the time, could you please point me to some resource or anything that will get me started on laying out a good exception policy?

Comment: Hmm, I'd start by searching this site for questions and answers about exceptions. There is a lot of great advice scattered from here to there. You can also limit the search to just the [tag:c++] tag, although there's plenty of general advice on using exceptions hidden in the [tag:c#], [tag:java], and other language-specific tags. Honestly, though, I wouldn't worry too much about an exception "policy". Just derive a handful of exception classes that are meaningful for your application from either `std::exception` or `CException`, and throw those as appropriate.

Comment: The most important advice is to always catch the more specific derived exception class because that's the only one you know how to handle. Don't just catch all exceptions, because then you'll get stuff like out-of-memory exceptions that you know you can't deal with. Those should just bubble up the stack to a global exception handler that logs them and ends the app gracefully. I've posted more elaborate versions of this advice in answer form to plenty of other questions on here if you need more explanation. @anish

Answer (score 1):

You could simply define your custom error codes to not "clash" with the Windows return values. Of course, you don't know when Microsoft will add new return values, so this will always be a little flakey.

You could try something like this:

```
enum MYERR
{
    MYERR_FIRST_ERROR   = 0x0F000000, /* large and unlikely to be used */
    MYERR_SECOND_ERROR,
    MYERR_THIRD_ERROR,
    /* and so on */
};
```

But, as Cody Gray notes above, I think you're better off returning a standard error code from `DoModal`, such as `IDABORT` instead of overloading the return codes like that. Then simply have a secondary error code that users must explicitly retrieve, which is your own "internal" error code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum instead of macro-defined return code, with namespace in order to avoid name-conflict. Look at the [Boost Error Handling Policy](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/policy/pol_ref/error_handling_policies.html) :

```
namespace boost { namespace math { namespace policies {

enum error_policy_type
{
   throw_on_error = 0, // throw an exception.
   errno_on_error = 1, // set ::errno & return 0, NaN, infinity or best guess.
   ignore_error = 2, // return 0, NaN, infinity or best guess.
   user_error = 3  // call a user-defined error handler.
};

}}} // namespaces
```

Comment: His problem isn't name conflicts, it's *value* conflicts. By defining `error_policy_type::errno_on_error` to equal 1, it will still clash with `IDOK`, which is also equal to 1.

Comment: you can declare an enum without a value, and using as is. [Pros and Cons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623452/the-use-of-enum-without-a-variable-name)

Comment: That's irrelevant here. Declaring enums without explicit values just means that the compiler will automatically assign them. In 99.99% of implementations, it will do just what you expect and start assigning with 0 and increment by 1.

Comment: @georgesl, Like Cody said, this would clash with various Win32 definitions. Also, my errors are also currently inside an `enum`.